# Initializer element is not constant

Tags: c

I'm trying to declare a dummy `head*` as global variable but the IDE is giving this error:

```
initializer element is not constant
```

How could I fix that?

```
typedef struct MyNode{
    struct MyNode *next;
    int value;
}Node;

//Declare a global variable
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
head->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Instead let the dummy be `Node head; head.next = NULL;` and then use `&head` where the code previously used `head`.

Comment: IDEs do not issue this kind of errors. What compiler is this?

Comment: Please clarify what your constraints and requirements are. The obvious thing to do is just to declare the `head` variable as a global but then do the initialisation within a function.

Comment: @kaylum, but how? How to declare the head variable as a global but then do the initialisation within a function?

Comment: Yes, `head` can be initialised to `NULL`, since `NULL`  is a (macro that expands to) a constant expression.

Comment: @Peter: I was asking whether it makes sense in his app. Does he need a pointer?

Comment: A better question is whether he needs a global.

Comment: @Peter: That's a good question. "better"? That's highly subjective...

Comment: Well, no, in this case it is not subjective.   If an answer to question A can mean it is not necessary to even ask question B, then question A is a better question by many measures ( (more widely applicable, more general, more enduring, etc).   A carefully considered answer on whether a global is needed can completely eliminate the question of whether a pointer is needed, which in turn can eliminate the problems of initialising a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is just to declare the head variable as a global but then do the initialisation within a function.

```
typedef struct MyNode{
    struct MyNode *next;
    int value;
} Node;

Node *head;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    head = malloc(sizeof *head);
    if (!head) {
        /* error */
        exit(-1);
    }

    head->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have assignments outside functions.
Here you find a complete discussion:
[Structure member assignment causing syntax error when not inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664514/structure-member-assignment-causing-syntax-error-when-not-inside-a-function)

Comment: Good cross-reference.

Answer (score 1):

The C11 standard states in section 6.7.9 part 4:

*All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.*

Your pointer `head` is being initialized with a function call, which is not a constant expression.  The only way to initialize it with a function call is to declare it inside of a function (however, this will not work if it's declared with `static` due to the above restriction).  Alternatively, you can just let the pointer be initialized by default to `NULL`, and then assign it with `malloc()` later on.

Answer (score 0):

From the C99 standard:

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Hence,

```
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

is not allowed. You can initialize `head` with a constant expression, such as NULL.

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

Of course, statements like:

```
head->next = NULL;
```

are not allowed outside functions. Hence, proper initialization of `head` has to be done in a function. One way to do that would be:

```
Node* head = NULL;

Node* createNode()
{
   Node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
   node->value = 0;
   node->next = NULL;
   return node;
}

int main()
{
   head = createNode();
   ...
}
```

Comment: why is there `*node` inside `malloc()` instead of `Node` ?? @RSahu

Comment: If `head` is global (as the OP has requested) won't that code still get the same "initializer element is not constant" error?

Comment: It does give the same error @RSahu

Comment: @kaylum, good point. Now I am getting C++ and C mixed up.

Comment: @Nikola, Using of `x = malloc(sizeof(*x));` is a good idiom to follow. It avoids mistakes in the argument to `sizeof`.