# Declaring and initializing structure variable outside main()

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, initialization, global-variables

I am trying to declare a structure outside main function. I was able to declare its variables outside the main function but when i try to initialize them the way shown below:

```
struct test
{
int a;
};
struct test abc;
abc.a=1;
int main()
{
printf("%d\n",abc.a);
return 0;
}
```

I am getting error `error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token`. When i initialize the structure variables at the time I declared them, everything goes smooth but i am getting an error when using the way above. Why is it happening and what does this error mean?

Comment: You can't use statements outside of a function.  That includes assignments.  You *can* include an initializer with a declaration.  In your case, you want `struct test abc = {1};`  That's an initializer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664514/structure-member-assignment-causing-syntax-error-when-not-inside-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structure member assignment causing syntax error when not inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664514/structure-member-assignment-causing-syntax-error-when-not-inside-a-function)

Comment: @Hitokiri yes it answers my quest but partially. i am still not able to understand what this error is trying to tell. i understood the concept. Can you explain about this error ?